# reducing nested dictionaries defined by a boolean operator

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, reduce

Suppose I have a payload like the following:

```
payload = {
    "OR": [
        {
            "AND" : [[1,2,3],[3,4]]
        }, # ([1,2,3] AND [3,4]) --> [3]
        {
            "OR" : [
                {
                    "AND" : [
                        {
                            "OR" : [[10,11],[12,13]]
                        }, # ([10,11] OR [12,13]) ---> [10,11,12,13]
                        {
                            "AND": [[11,13]]
                        }  # ([11,13]) ---> [11,13]
                    ]
                }, # ([10,11,12,13] AND [11,13]) ---> [11,13]
                {
                    "AND" : [[14,15],[15]]
                }  # ([14,15] AND [15]) ---> [15]
            ]
        }  # ([11,13] OR [15]) ---> [11,13,15]
    ]
} # ([3] OR [11,13,15]) ---> [3,11,13,15]
```

I am okay at this point utilizing the strings `AND` and `OR` as Boolean operators, which feel as though they map to `set.intersection()` and `set.union()` respectively.

I have commented in the dictionary of nested `bool_operator`:`[...]` blocks how each "block" would reduce down based on the operator.

Given all this, I would like to reduce this payload down to the following:

```
[3,11,13,15]
```

I understand this to require recursion, and to that end, have created a function that reduces a list of lists given a plain text Boolean operator:

```
from functools import reduce

def reduce_block(bool_operator, block):

    bool_operator_set_hash = {
        'AND':'intersection',
        'OR':'union'
    }

    return reduce(
            lambda x,y: getattr(set(x),bool_operator_set_hash.get(bool_operator.upper()))(set(y)),
            block
        )
```

This works well for a single Boolean operator and list of lists containing values.  But, I'm having trouble with the recursion.  Any suggestions?  am I over-complicating this?  Would like to turn this into a tidy library for use.

Many thanks in advance for any insight.

**UPDATE 8/12/2019**

@Ajax1234's solution worked very well, until I encountered a situation where there were > 2 blocks for a given Boolean operator, e.g.

```py
payload = {'OR': [
              {'AND': [
                        [
                             ('5657',),
                             ('5698',)               
                        ]
                   ]
              },
              {'AND': [
                        [
                             ('6101',),
                             ('5420',),
                             ('5334',),
                             ('5439',)
                        ]
                   ]
              },
              {'AND': [
                        [
                             ('5802',),
                             ('6005',),     
                             ('6675',),
                             ('5878',)
                        ]
                   ]
              },
              {'AND': [
                        [
                             ('6265',),
                             ('6157',),
                             ('6238',),
                             ('6189',),
                             ('6191',)
                        ]
                   ]
              }
        ]
    }
```

To update the requirements: ideally would *also* work on a payload like the one above.

**UPDATE 8/13/2019**

Still running into edge cases, e.g. the following payload:

```py
payload = {
    'AND': [
        {
            'OR': [
                [('6101',)],
                [('6265',)]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In this situation, my output is the single valued set: `{'OR'}`,  though I would expect `{('6101',),('6265',)}`.  Appreciated your help so far @ajax1234, any suggestions?

Comment: what do u need `bool_operator` for?

Comment: @Samha', `bool_operator` is used to grab a method from a `set` instance; needed to allow strings like `AND` and `OR`, but need methods from `set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `functools.reduce` with `getattr`:

```
from functools import reduce
def _eval(_load):
   [[op, _vals]] = _load.items()
   if len(_vals) == 1:
     return set(_vals[0]) if not isinstance(_vals[0], dict) else _eval(_vals[0])
   return reduce(lambda l, r:getattr(_eval(l) if isinstance(l, dict) else set(l), f'__{op.lower()}__')(_eval(r) if isinstance(r, dict) else set(r)),  _vals)

print(_eval(payload))
```

Output:

```
{11, 3, 13, 15}
```

---

```
print(_eval(new_payload))
```

Output:

```
{('5878',), ('6265',), ('5698',), ('6189',), ('5334',), ('5439',), ('6238',), ('5420',), ('5802',), ('6157',), ('6101',), ('6191',), ('6005',), ('6675',), ('5657',)}
```

---

```
print(_eval(_new_payload))
```

Output:

```
{('6265',), ('6101',)}
```

Comment: Huzzah, hurray, amazing.  Works like a charm.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: worked like a charm, @ajax1234, *until* I hit a situation where I had > 2 blocks per operator.  I have spent some time looking at your answer to understand it, which I think that I do now.  But given how elegant this first solution was, I'm curious how you might alter it to fit the updated requirements?  Thanks.

Comment: @ghukill Please see my recent edit. `functools.reduce` works well in this situation.

Comment: Of course!  Really appreciate your thinking on this @ajax1234.

Comment: Back again @ajax1234; ran into another edge case.  Understand if you're just done with this little head-scratcher, otherwise, continue to appreciate your help!

Comment: I was very close, but hadn't made the leap to run through `_eval()` again.  Thanks so much @ajax1234!  Learning a lot through this tidy little example.

Comment: @ghukill No problem, glad to help!